# Advice for designing a relationship in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to connect 2 players with a connecting table. That connecting table must have an active flag, and possibly more attributes going forward.  I want to be able to associate 2 `Players` to the `PlayerLink` an `active_player` and `passive_player`, so that I may say `player_link.active_player.name`.

I have tried the following but am not getting the behavior I want.  Perhaps I am missing something silly, or approaching it incorrectly.

```
module V1
  class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :player_link

  end    
end

module V1
  class PlayerLink < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :active_player, class_name: "Player", foreign_key: :active_player_id
    has_one :passive_player, class_name: "Player", foreign_key: :passive_player_id
  end
end
```

`schema.rb` entry:

```
create_table "player_links", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "active_player_id"
    t.integer  "passive_player_id"
    t.boolean  "active"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

Test query that blows up:

```
V1::PlayerLink.where(active: true).each do |l|
  l.active_player.update_attribute(:foo, bar)
  l.passive_player.update_attribute(:foo, bar
end
```

With the error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: players.active_player_id: SELECT  "players".* FROM "players"  WHERE "players"."active_player_id" = ?
```

Bonus:  Why is Rails querying agains `players`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called *self-referential associations* - I had trouble the first time I did them as well.

Try modifying your controller logic as follows:

```rb
module V1
  class Player < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :player_links

  end    
end

module V1
  class PlayerLink < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :player, :foreign_key => "active_player_id"
    belongs_to :passive_player, :class_name => "Player", :foreign_key => "passive_player_id"

  end
end
```

For more info, see [RailsCast #163](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association).